# How to overcome undeclared error in lex file

Tags: c, programming-languages, lex

I am new to lex and I write very simple program in the file ilk.l

```
%option main
%%
float val;
[+-]?[0-9]*(\.)?[0-9]+      {sscanf(yytext, "%f", &val);
                             printf(">%f<", val);     }
```

After saving this file, I run the following commands;

```
-bash-4.2$ lex ilk.l
-bash-4.2$ gcc lex.yy.c
ilk.l: In function ‘yylex’:
ilk.l:3:1: error: ‘val’ undeclared (first use in this function)
 float val;
 ^
ilk.l:3:1: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
-bash-4.2$
```

I am confused about the reason for error. Can you explain what I am doing wrong and how can I correct it?

Comment: I think you might need to read the Lex (flex?) manual a little closer. When and where will general C code be allowed?

Comment: [Syntax of the rules section in a (f)lex file.](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Rules-Section.html#Rules-Section)

Answer (score 1):

Variables should be declared in declaration section as follows:

```
%{
//declaration section
float val;
%}
%option main
%%
[+-]?[0-9]*(\.)?[0-9]+ {sscanf(yytext, "%f", &val);printf(">%f<", val);}
%%
```

Comment: Not necessarily. That declares a global (file-scope) variable. A local variable is declared where OP declared it. *But the declaration must be indented*